# How do I compare a value to a decimal using a comma separator?

Tags: c#, localization, decimal-point

I have some decimal input from my DataGridView; let's say `4,3`.

I want to compare if it is between `3,5` and `4,4`.

How should I write the numbers `3,5` and `4,4` in my code?

With my current attempt, I get some errors like

> ; expected

> } expected

> Operator || cannot be applied

I tried with Cultureinfo but I do not know how exactly use it.

Here is my code so far:

```cs
var updateLabStar = db.PatientLab.Where(x => x.BloodUrinId == item.BloodUrinId).FirstOrDefault();

if (Convert.ToDecimal(Result) < 3,5 || Convert.ToDecimal(Result) > 4,4)
{
    updateLabStar.Interval = updateLabStar.Result + " *";
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: You can't use a comma as a decimal separator for literal values in your code, you must use a period. The `CultureInfo` only affects how the decimal is displayed, not how it is stored or compared. If you want to use a comma for literals in your code, you will need to define them as strings then parse them into decimals using the appropriate culture.

Comment: @DM , thank you for your response. I have tried by many way like string.Format(..., "{0:N}", parsed)and I'am sure I'am doing in wrong way. Would you please show me how do you mean? Thank you in advance

Comment: @DM, I disagree that "`CultureInfo` only affects how the decimal is displayed" because it implements the `IFromatProvider` interface which can be used to parse data for example.

Comment: @HelenTekie Sure, take a look at [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qSHyEh).

Comment: @Qwertyluk valid point, but the representation once it's parsed is identical to any other culture. That's what I was getting at. It doesn't make sense to have a culture once you have a `decimal` because C# only handles a `decimal` one way.

Comment: @DM, Thank you my dear. It's working now perfectly. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

[How to write decimal literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types#real-literals).

```
var updateLabStar = db.PatientLab.Where(x => x.BloodUrinId == item.BloodUrinId).FirstOrDefault();

if (Convert.ToDecimal(Result) < 3.5m || Convert.ToDecimal(Result) > 4.4m)
{
    updateLabStar.Interval = updateLabStar.Result + " *";
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response, but I have stil the same problem with addning "m" or "M"